# How to extract the content within the dashed line

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I have text that has some content in the markdown format and it comprises of two parts first part that is surrounded by dashed line is the meta data and the remaining part after the dashed line is the actual content.

My format is like this:

```
---
toc:
    customization:
        title: Customization
        themes: Themes
        plugins: Plugins
nav: 5
---

summary: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel diam purus.
body:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel diam purus.`
```

I want to extract the content within those dashed lines and have store in the separate HashMap(do not want to store those dashes in the map) and similarly separate hashMap for the actual content.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content/" + url + ".md"));

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split(":");

    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        if (!columns[i].isEmpty() && !columns[i].contains("---")) {
            map.put(columns[0], columns[1]);
        }
    }
}

scanner.close();
System.out.println(map);
```

Can anyone tell me how can I extract those lines within dashes and stored it in the separate HashMap and store the actual content in the separate HashMap?

Comment: Something like `---(.*?)---` ? Or maybe `\-{3}(.*?)\-{3}`

Comment: could please give me a little example ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to do. But that is a quick regex to capture all the text between the dashes. You could also use a boolean switch like in the existing answer.

Comment: Could you put some example result? I am not sure what value have key `toc` and `customization`.

Comment: @cricket_007 - could please tell me how to capture all the text between the dashes using regex ?

Answer (score 3):

Simply keep track of which map to use:

```
Map<String, String> regularMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> separateMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

Map<String, String> currentMap = regularMap;
boolean inDashes = false;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if(line.equals("---")) {
       // switch state
       inDashes = !inDashes;
       currentMap = inDashes ? separateMap : regularMap;
    } else {
        String[] columns = line.split(":");
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            if (!columns[i].isEmpty()) {
                currentMap.put(columns[0], columns[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting ArrayOutOfBound exception 1 when I run this code.
and one more thing in some of my file I do not have `:` in the content i,e,. after the dashed line section. how can I parse at that time ?

Answer (score 0):

This simple code should work fine.

```
public static void parseFile(String url) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content/" + url + ".md"));

    // create a two maps
    HashMap<String, String> metaData = new HashMap();
    HashMap<String, String> content = new HashMap();

    // and a marker
    boolean isMetaData = false;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
        if ("---".equals(nextLine)) { // if line equals "---" then
            isMetaData = !isMetaData; // switch a marker
            continue; // and skip this line
        }

        // add to proper map the value from the line
        addPropertyToMap(isMetaData ? metaData : content, nextLine.split(":"));
    }
    scanner.close();

    System.out.println(metaData);
    System.out.println(content);
}

private static void addPropertyToMap(HashMap<String, String> map, String[] columns){
    if(columns.length == 1){
        // if your key don't have value, replace it with an empty string
        map.put(columns[0].trim(), "");
    } else {
        map.put(columns[0].trim(), columns[1].trim());
    }
}
```

When you run this code, you should get the following result:

```
{themes=Themes, nav=5, customization=, plugins=Plugins, toc=, title=Customization}
{summary=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel diam purus., body=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel diam purus.}
```

Comment: in case I do not have the `:` in the content section how can I put that in the Map ?

Comment: Do you have any example? I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: in case the file in this format
`---
key: value
description: some description
props:
  p1: value1
  p2: value2
theme: default
date: 20-3-1202
---


this is a paragraph

this is another paragraph

this is another paragraph this is another paragraph`

Comment: Could you tell, what result do you expect? I think this code should work for your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for parsing and extracting a data is using a **Model class**, then parsing the data into the **model object** instances and store them in a **List**.

## Model

```
public class Model {

    // Fields
    private String toc;
    private String customization;
    private String title;
    private String themes;
    private String plugins;
    private int nav;

    // No-arg Default Constructor
    public Model() {};

    // Getters & Setters
    public String getToc() {
        return toc;
    }

    public void setToc(String toc) {
        this.toc = toc;
    }

    public String getCustomization() {
        return customization;
    }

    public void setCustomization(String customization) {
        this.customization = customization;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getThemes() {
        return themes;
    }

    public void setThemes(String themes) {
        this.themes = themes;
    }

    public String getPlugins() {
        return plugins;
    }

    public void setPlugins(String plugins) {
        this.plugins = plugins;
    }

    public int getNav() {
        return nav;
    }

    public void setNav(int nav) {
        this.nav = nav;
    }
}
```

## Test

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    private static final int OBJECT_LINE_LENGTH = 6;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String url = "testFile";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content/" + url + ".md"));
        boolean isInContent = false;
        int lineCounter = 0;
        String lines[] = new String[OBJECT_LINE_LENGTH];
        List<Model> objectList = new ArrayList<Model>();

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            if(line.equals("---")) {
                if(isInContent == false) {
                    isInContent = true;
                    continue;
                } else {
                    isInContent = false;
                }
            }

            if(!isInContent) {
                continue;
            }

            lines[lineCounter++] = line;

            if(lineCounter == 6) {
                lineCounter = 0;
                objectList.add(parseObject(lines));
            }

        }
        scanner.close();

        printObjectList(objectList);
    }


    private static Model parseObject(String lines[]) {
        Model model = new Model();

        model.setToc(Arrays.copyOfRange(lines, 1, 4).toString());
        model.setCustomization(Arrays.copyOfRange(lines, 2, 4).toString());
        model.setTitle(lines[2].split(":")[1].trim());
        model.setThemes(lines[3].split(":")[1].trim());
        model.setPlugins(lines[4].split(":")[1].trim());
        model.setNav(Integer.parseInt(lines[5].split(":")[1].trim()));

        return model;
    }

    private static void printObjectList(List<Model> objectList) {
        for(Model m : objectList) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Title  : " + m.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Themes : " + m.getThemes());
            System.out.println("Plugins: " + m.getPlugins());
            System.out.println("Nav    : " + m.getNav());
        }
    }

}
```

## Sample md file used for Test

```
---
toc:
    customization:
        title: Customization
        themes: Themes
        plugins: Plugins
nav: 5
---
---
toc:
    customization:
        title: anotherCustomization
        themes: anotherThemes
        plugins: anotherPlugins
nav: 10
---
---
toc:
    customization:
        title: ThirdCustomization
        themes: ThirdTheme
        plugins: ThirdPlugin
nav: 15
---




---
toc:
    customization:
        title: fourthCustomization
        themes: fourthTheme
        plugins: fourthPlugin
nav: 20
---
```

## Test Output

```
Title  : Customization
Themes : Themes
Plugins: Plugins
Nav    : 5

Title  : anotherCustomization
Themes : anotherThemes
Plugins: anotherPlugins
Nav    : 10

Title  : ThirdCustomization
Themes : ThirdTheme
Plugins: ThirdPlugin
Nav    : 15

Title  : fourthCustomization
Themes : fourthTheme
Plugins: fourthPlugin
Nav    : 20
```